# How to specify 'x' and 'y' attributes of a textNode created and appended through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I need to specify the exact location where my dynamically generated pieces of text should go in a webpage. How do I do that?

Comment: text nodes don't have attributes, you'll have to wrap them in an element before you can style them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your text in an inline element which you can style, then use absolute positioning on this element.

```
function placeText(x, y, text) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.position = 'absolute';
    span.style.top = y + 'px';
    span.style.left = x + 'px';
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    return span;
}

placeText(200, 300, 'hello world');
```